# Получить дату и время часового пояса js?

Tags: jquery, время, дата, javascript

Мне нужно получить дату определенного часового пояса я использую такое

```
var d = new Date();
```

но получается только дата страны в которой находится пользователь - как к примеру получить дату и время Лондона или Сингапура?

Comment: Смещение времени компьютера пользователя относительно UTC (Universal Coordinated Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы узнать смещение часового пояса в минутах можно использовать

`d=new Date()
time_zone=d.getTimezoneOffset()`

для установки даты другого пояса надо прибавить минуты часового пояса к минутам даты

Comment: а смещение относительно чего??

Comment: относительно местного времени пользователся?

Comment: относительно GMT

Comment: А как быть, когда меняется часовой пояс? зимнее-летнее время.
Мне к примеру нужно время израильтян. но они перескакивают по поясам.